# Modelica combiTimeTable

Tags: modelica

I have a few questions regarding combitimeTables: I tired to import a txt file (3 columns: first time + 2 measured data)into a combitimeTable. - Does the txt file have to have the following header #1; double K(x,y) - Is it right, that the table name in combitimeTable have to have the same name than the variable after double (in my case K)? - I get errors if i try to connect 2 outputs of the table (column 1 and column2). Do I have to specify how many columns that I want to import?

And: Why do i have to use in the path "/" instead of "\" ?

```
Modelica Code:
Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable combiTimeTable(
 tableOnFile=true,
 tableName="K",
 fileName="D:/test.txt")
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

The standard text file format for CombiTables is:

`#1
double K(4,3)
  0  1  10
  1  3  20
  2  5  30
  3  7  40`

In this case note the "tableName" parameter I would set as a modifier to the CombiTable (or CombiTimeTable) is "K".  And yes, the numbers in parenthesis indicate the dimensions of the data to the tool, so in this case 4 rows and 3 columns.

Regarding the path separator "/" or "\", the backslash character "\" which is the path separator in Windows where as the forward slash "/" is the path separator on Unix like systems (e.g. Linux).  The issue is that in most libraries the backslash is used as an escape character.  So for example "\n" indicates new line and "\t" indicates tab so if my file name string was "D:\nextfolder\table.txt", this would actually look something like:

`D:
extfolder    able.txt`

Depending on your Modelica simulation tool however it might correct this.  So if you used a file selection dialog box to choose your file, the tool should automatically switch the file separator character to the forward slash "/" and your text would look like:

`combiTimeTable(
    tableOnFile=true,
    tableName="K",
    fileName="D:/nextfolder/table.txt",
    columns=2:3)`

If you are getting errors in your connect statement, I would guess you might have forgotten the "columns" parameter.  The default value for this parameter comes from the "table" parameter (which is empty by default because there are zero rows by two columns), not from the data in the file.  So when you are reading data from a file you need to explicitly set this